# copy from std::priority_que into typdef edge

Tags: c++, queue

I have `typedef std::pair<int , std::pair<std::string, std::string>> edge;`

I placed my edges into a `std::priority_que<edge, std::vector<edge>, Compare> que;`

When I now try to `que.pop()` back into an edge variable a get an error. Why is that?

```
que = priority_que with edges
edge e = que.pop() // this does not work
```

Comment: `std::priority_que` is not in the standard library. Do you mean `std::priority_queue`?

Comment: In the future, please provide a [mre]. Also include more info like the actual error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`std::priority_queue::pop()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/pop) doesn't return anything.

You need to call `top()` first to extract element.

```
edge e = que.top();
que.pop();
```